# Figurative meaning for "open a parenthesis"?

Tags: meaning

[In this article](http://rcecafe.net/?p=183) one can find the following construct:

> ... To answer this question, it is ... necessary to open a parenthesis.

( And then the author goes into some details. But he does not literally use any parenthesis as I do right here. )

So my question is -- did the author invent this figure of speech, or does it exist in contemporary English ?

**Upd.** As **FumbleFingers** have mentioned below, [Google Books](http://books.google.com/) search for ["will open a parenthesis"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22will+open+a+parenthesis%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) shows the meaning *"to be mentioned in parentheses"* to be rather common for this expression.

The moral: there is not just Google, there are also Google Books. )

Comment: [Here](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22will+open+a+parenthesis%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) are 24 more instances of people writing/saying *"I will open a parenthesis"*, but it's a trivial extension of meaning, so I doubt any of them were copying anyone else - they just thought it, so they wrote/said it. Voting to close as "general reference".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I should have googled with a "will". How do I close this ? ( I do not want to delete the question, though, as I like the expression and want a reference to exist )

Comment: I don't think you get a chance to "close" your own question - you just have to let others do it for you. And unless you have access to OED you'd have a job establishing online that there is/was a rare obsolete **verb** *"to parenthese"* meaning *"to intersperse, **as with parentheses**"*. It cites "1635 J. Hayward tr. *Biondi's Banish'd Virg.* 226 A faint voyce, whose‥lamentations were often parenthesed with sighes and teares.    Ibid. 228 Shee (parenthesing her words with greedy kisses) thus bespake him."

Comment: Well, I think this question is now properly closed with an answer (and the above comment as well).

Comment: It just means no-one can post any more answers. But the question stays here, so if anyone asks a similar one they might find this first. Anyone can still post comments, and nico can *amend* his answer if he wants. I think people can still upvote both Q and A, but I don't know if you get the rep points if they do.

Comment: Thank you. Makes sense to me. [ As a personal view, I'd rather avoid closing _any_ question ( unless they provoke flamewars etc ) then -- but it is just my opinion, and I have nothing against those who close questions that _do_ have a good answer ) ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OED defines **parenthesis** as:

> 1.a An explanatory or qualifying word, clause, or sentence inserted into a passage with which it has not necessarily any grammatical connexion, and from which it is usually marked off by round or square brackets, dashes, or commas.
>
> **1659** in Burton's Diary (1828) IV. 283 You see the inconveniency of a long parenthesis; we have forgot the sense that went before. **1762** Sterne Tr. Shandy V. xvi, The phenomenon had not been worth a parenthesis.

This is the rethorical meaning of the word `parenthesis`. Because you often put a parenthesis between round brackets, the term is also used to indicate the bracket symbol `()`. However, a parenthesis need not necessarily to be put in parentheses!

Interestingly, the OED  also lists the (obsolete) meaning of digression

> †1.b A passage introduced into a context with which it has no connexion; a digression. Obs.
>
> **1600** Heywood 1st Pt. Edw. IV Wks. 1874 I. 29 Away with this parenthesis of words. **1654** Gataker Disc. Apol. 4 But let this go for a Parenthesis; return we to our task. **1757** H. Walpole Lett. H. Mann 5 May (1846) III. 288, I thought you would prefer this parenthesis of politics.

So, it is clear that the expression "to open a parenthesis" is used to say: "I will now start to talk about something not completely related for a while, then come back to my previous subject".

As a side note: in Italian and French you can use *aprire una parentesi* or *ouvrir une parenthèse* (to open a parenthesis) as an idiomatic expression to indicate a digression.

Comment: Thank you for your time, it's a great answer! Also, the side note makes perfect sense, as the author of the cited text is quite likely to be a native Italian speaker